# How to serialize/deserialize list with interface

Tags: c#, serialization, yaml, yamldotnet

I've trying to serialize and deserialize a list with an interface, the problem is that yamldotnet cannot deserialize it.

I've show it to you with an example:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; }
}
class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CustomThing { get; set; } = "1a";
}
class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSomething { get; set; } = true;
}
```

When I now try to serialize this:

```
var serializer = new Serializer();
List<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>()
{
    new Cat() { Name = "Oscar" },
    new Dog() { Name = "WuffWuff" }
};
var writer = File.CreateText("test.yml");
serializer.Serialize(writer, animals);
writer.Close();
```

The result of this would be

```
- Name: Oscar
  CustomThing: 1a
- Name: WuffWuff
  IsSomething: true
```

I understand that as this point yamldotnet cannot know which types that are, and it is needed that the class types are also definied inside the `yml`

So how can I archive this?

I've already tried to find something in the [documentation](http://aaubry.net/pages/yamldotnet.html) but there are only examples and nothing with interfaces / list's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type of a node using [tags](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292):

```
- !cat
  Name: Oscar
  CustomThing: 1a
- !dog
  Name: WuffWuff
  IsSomething: true
```

You will need to tell YamlDotNet what types correspond to `!cat` and `!dog`:

```
deserializer.RegisterTagMapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:cat", typeof(Cat));
deserializer.RegisterTagMapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:dog", typeof(Dog));
```

**Note**: `!` is a shorthand for `tag:yaml.org,2002:`. When registering the tag mapping, we need to use the full Uri.

Here's an example code very similar to yours: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GZtqvL

---

The serializer also supports emitting tags. To activate this behavior, you need to specify the `SerializationOptions.Roundtrip` flag in the constructor. At the moment it is not possible to specify tag mappings on the serializer, though.

Comment: but the serializer still doesn't add this to the ``.yml``. Is there something similar to the method in the deserializer?

Comment: Specifying `SerializationOptions.Roundtrip` on the serializer should add the tags.

Comment: Can you edit this in you'r answer, then its perfect!

Comment: When I use ``SerializationOptions.Roundtrip`` I do not need to Register any tag mappings, but how can the serializer do this custom things that it will be one ``cat`` and not ``Namespace.Cat, Version...``?

Comment: You will still need to register the mappings on the serializer, unless you are happy with the default scheme, which uses the full name of the type.

Comment: How do I add this to the serializer there is no method like that in the deserializer?

Comment: Humm... I was certain that there was a way to register the mapping, but apparently this has not been implemented. I'll have to implement this soon. Unfortunately I don't think that there is any workaround.

Comment: `!` is *not* a shorthand for `tag:yaml.org,2002:`. `!!` is (unless redefined by a `%TAG` directive). Since you are the author of YamlDotNet, is this a bug in the implementation or just a typo in this answer?

Comment: You are correct, this is definitely a bug in the implementation. Thanks for pointing it out. [I have opened an issue here about this](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/241)